# ant propertyregex: problem with \ in paths

Tags: java, ant

When I am doing something like this:

```xml
<propertyregex input="${escaped.std}" regexp=".*[/\\]data[/\\](.*)" select="\1" property="relative.std"/>
```

where escaped.std is ex: *c:\test\data\subfolder1\subfolder2*
it returns *subfolder1subfolder2* (the path without the '\')

I tried to change '\' to '\\' but it just removed '\\' from the path.

Where is the problem?

Comment: Are you reading the property escaped.std from a file?  When you say 'returns' what do you mean?  (How are you looking at the value of relative.std?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the latest version of ant-contrib.

It does work fine when using ant-contrib 1.0b2 (I get the same issue when using version 0.6).

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions
first with [antcontrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/)
second with [Flaka](http://code.google.com/p/flaka/)

```
<project xmlns:fl="antlib:it.haefelinger.flaka">
  <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml"/>

  <property name="escaped.std" value="c:\test\data\subfolder1\subfolder2"/>

  <!-- solution antcontrib-1.0b3.jar -->
  <propertyregex input="${escaped.std}" regexp=".:\\(\w+\\){2}(.+)" select="\2" property="relative.std_ac"/>

  <echo>$${relative.std_ac} => ${relative.std_ac}</echo>

  <!-- solution with Flaka -->
  <fl:let>
    relative.std_fl ::= replace(property['escaped.std'],'$2','.:\\\\(\\w+\\\\){2}(.+)')
  </fl:let>

  <echo>$${relative.std_fl} => ${relative.std_fl}</echo>
</project>
```

output :

```
 [echo] ${relative.std_ac} => subfolder1\subfolder2
 [echo] ${relative.std_fl} => subfolder1\subfolder2
```